# О родАх и рОдах

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно говорить во множественном числе слово "род": "роды" или "рода" (понятно, что не рОды)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Слово **РОД** многозначное.
1. Если речь идет об основной общности людей первобытного общества, представляющая союз больших семей, находящихся в родственных отношениях, то во множественном числе правильно говорить "**родЫ**". 2. Если *род* - грамматическая категория, то во множественном числе правильная форма - **рОды** (напр.: *рОды и виды литературы*). 3.Если *род* - это тип, вид чего-либо, то форма множ.числа - **родА** (напр.: *родА войск*).

Comment: рОды литературы - это никак не грамматическая категория. Грамматическая категория - это мужской, женский и стредний род (в русском; других языках есть ещё).  
Про литературу - это "В систематике: группа, объединяющая близкие виды" (Кузнецов). Они же - в биологии (рОды такого-то семейства).  
Не стоило бы упоминать, но это значение трудно отличить от №3 по вашей классификации.

Comment: Справедливое замечание. Во втором значении должен быть другой пример: рОды существительных и прилагательных.

Comment: @olsa, дело не замене примера. Продлема в том, что ваш исходный пример (про виды и рОды литературы) по всем имеющимся справочникам действительно относится к случаю №2. А вот про войска или там ещй какие структурные подразделения - родА (войск) - №3. И как различить, где какой вариант, не очень понятно. В общем-то об одно и том же речь. Подозреваю, что это военный сленг просто "продавил" своё виденье нормы.

Comment: А если так: "мужской и средний роды существительных"?

Comment: @olsa,я не о правильности вашего текста, я в ней не сомневаюсь.  
Я о сомнительности разделения "рода" в значении систематической единицы (со множетвенным рОды) и структурного типа (со множественным родА). Вряд ли кто-либо чувствует границу между ними.

Comment: Вы забыли еще один вариант. Роды - как процесс рождения детей. Причем в этом смысле мне неизвестно единственное число.

Comment: Не забыл. Он тут не к месту. У "процесса" нет единственного числа, ему путаться не с чем.

Answer (score 0):

Полностью согласен - категория, вид, тип и т. д. - это одно и то же в смысле классификация. родА - это скорей всего сленг военных, только от них и слышал это корявое - "родА", это как и компАс и Алкоголь (на первый слог) (моряки не плавают, а ходят ))) и понеслось) - проф. извращения языка.